# How do i get the played move by comparing two different fens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess, python-chess, fen

So I have two fens. One gotten before the move and one after. How can I get the played move by comparing these 2 fens to each other and returning the answer in uci or any other format. I am using the python-chess library so maybe there is a way to get the played move by comparing two different board objects as well?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! I used the board objects that the chess python library makes and parsed
those for the UCI of the move played.

```
nums = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d", 5:"e", 6:"f", 7:"g", 8:"h"}
def get_uci(board1, board2, who_moved):
    str_board = str(board1).split("\n")
    str_board2 = str(board2).split("\n")
    move = ""
    flip = False
    if who_moved == "w":
        for i in range(8)[::-1]:
            for x in range(15)[::-1]:
                if str_board[i][x] != str_board2[i][x]:
                    if str_board[i][x] == "." and move == "":
                        flip = True
                    move+=str(nums.get(round(x/2)+1))+str(9-(i+1))
    else:
        for i in range(8):
            for x in range(15):
                if str_board[i][x] != str_board2[i][x]:
                    if str_board[i][x] == "." and move == "":
                        flip = True
                    move+=str(nums.get(round(x/2)+1))+str(9-(i+1))
    if flip:
        move = move[2]+move[3]+move[0]+move[1]
    return move
```

Comment: Nice, great work! Does this also cover moves where King and Rock swap or when a pawn gets upgraded to a queen?

Comment: @MartinS Hi! This was long ago and funnily enough I had this exact problem only a few days ago again! I decided to rewrite the code since this one is not very good and doesn't work for all cases. Please see the edited answer for an updated version that should work for most if not all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the constructs provided by the `Board` object:

```
for move in board.legal_moves:
    board.push(move)
    if board.board_fen() == new_board.board_fen():
        break
    _ = board.pop()
else:
    throw an exception...
```

This is using `chess.Board` where `board` is the original board, and `new_board` is equal to `board` plus one move. The `else` on the `for` loop should handle the cases where none of the legal moves on `board` will yield `new_board`, or where there are no legal moves on `board` at all. After this runs, and assuming the `else` did not fire, a new `Move` object will be pushed to `board.move_stack`.